# issue in regular expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I marked one peculiar thing in regular expression in jmeter:

My aim is to capture a substring of the following text (marked in bold) using regular expressions. For this I tried the following:

1. I have selected  “Text” from the “View Result tree” box and click on
   “Regular Expression” check box and then use regular expression 
   `viewstate\|/(.+?)=`  This is working fine.
2. But the same regular expression is not working when I am using
   “RegExp Tester” from drop down.

VIEWSTATE**|/wEPDwUJMjUyODUxNTQzEGRkFgJmD2QWAgIED2QWBAIJDw8WAh4EVGV4dAWKATxiPldlbGNvbWUmbmJzcDs8L2I+WFlaIEVGRzgxNzEgQUJDPGI+Jm5ic3A7QXMmbmJzcDs8L2I+UmFkaW9sb2dpc3Q8YnIgLz48Yj5EYXRlOiAmbmJzcDs8L2I+MTktQXByLTIwMTI8Yj4mbmJzcDtMb2NhdGlvbjombmJzcDs8L2I+ TU1QaGFybWFjeTEkZGdyTU0PZ2Q**=

Any Idea why this is happening like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark: Try `viewstate\|\/(.+?)=` and see if that works.

The rationale behind my guess: `/` might get misinterpreted as the regex delimiter, cutting short your regex.

Another idea (which would help if there were newlines in the input string that the `.` isn't matching):

```
viewstate\|\/([^=]+)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.. the second one clicked :)

Comment: Great. Does it also work if you remove the backslash from before the slash?

Comment: OK, then it's probably a newline in the input that was tripping up RegExp Tester.